# Nested struct: with invalid use of non-static member when define struct pointer

Tags: c++, struct, nested, static-members

This is a demo of link list, I defined a Node struct and it's pointer as head, but the compiler said : in--valid use of non-static member at the place:

```
Node* head;
```

Further more, if I do not pre-declare `struct Node` it will reports undeclared Node.

The code is as follows:

```
#ifndef LINKLIST_H
#define LINKLIST_H

template<typename T>
class LinkList
{
    struct Node;        //why declaration is required here   ???

    public:
    //  member function
        Node* Find(T x);
    //.....

    private:
        struct Node
        {
            T data;
            Node* next;

         //   Node():next(NULL){}
            Node(const T& d=0, Node* n=NULL):data(d),next(n){}
        };

        Node* head;                //ERROR    ??????  why?
};

template<typename T>
typename LinkList<T>::Node* LinkList<T>::Find(T x)
{
    Node* ptr=head->next;   
   //.....
```

}

## endif // LINKLIST_H

Run time error:

```
||=== Build: Release in Broken Keyboard (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
include\LinkList.h|41|error: invalid use of non-static data member 'LinkList<T>::head'|
include\LinkList.h|22|error: from this location|
include\LinkList.h|41|error: invalid use of non-static data member 'LinkList<T>::head'|
include\LinkList.h|95|error: from this location|
include\LinkList.h|95|error: default argument given for parameter 1 of 'void LinkList<T>::Insert(T, LinkList<T>::Node*)' [-fpermissive]|
include\LinkList.h|22|error: after previous specification in 'void LinkList<T>::Insert(T, LinkList<T>::Node*)' [-fpermissive]|
include\LinkList.h|95|error: default argument given for parameter 2 of 'void LinkList<T>::Insert(T, LinkList<T>::Node*)'|
include\LinkList.h|22|error: after previous specification in 'void LinkList<T>::Insert(T, LinkList<T>::Node*)'|
||=== Build failed: 8 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.

Comment: I add it.Please have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first forward declaration of struct Node is required since you are using it in the Find method before you provide the Node definition.
But you should not have the error in Node *head. I have tried your code in Visual Studio 2015 and instantiate the template in main, there is no error.

What is your compiler version?

Alon.

Comment: I use Code Blocks and the template class is declared and implemented in separate .h file. When I tried it in main.cpp, it ran correctly. So strange! Thank you for your reply!